# Экспорт содержимого грида в буфер обмена или эксель (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня вопрос, как при нажатии кнопки перенести содержимое грида в буфер обмена....или в Эксель? если можете напишите пожалуйста код
Спасибо))))
(язык C#(/WPF))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вкупе со всеми вопросами и предложениями, могу предложить только это, ибо не так хорошо знаком с вопросами производительности и прочего:

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                builder.Append(grid[j, i].Value.ToString());
                builder.Append(";");
            }
            builder.Replace(";", "|", builder.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1);
        string data = builder.ToString();
        data = data.Replace("|", "\n");
        Clipboard.SetText(data, TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue);
```

Здесь я использовал стандарт CSV для русского Excel, где значения разделяются символом ";", а строки просто символом перехода на следующую строку. При желании, можно выполнить следующий код, который сохранит для вас файл в формате CSV, свободно перевариваемый Excel:

```
        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\file.csv", data, Encoding.Default);
```

При использовании DataTable из пространства имён System.Data нужно заменить
    grid[j, i].Value.ToString()
на, к примеру,
    table.Rows[i][j].ToString()

Comment: И ещё вопрос....
А если использовать таблицу....как с неё скопировать?
я попытался этот код к таблице применить....т.е. как мне обратиться к
строкам,столбцам [j,i] таблицы ?

Comment: Я бы не советол использовать оператор '+=' в цикле, т.к. каждый раз создается новая строка, что может сказаться на производительности. Лучше все-таки использовать StringBulder.Append().

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает))))))))
Если комуто понадобится,добавьте вначале проекта
using System.Text;
и
using System.IO;, если создаёте файл.