# Как скопировать содержимое грида в эксель с учётом форматирования?

Tags: wpf, c#

Я задавал подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72168). Т.е. я в гриде определённые ячейки крашу зелёным, красным, шрифт жирный, и т.д. Как мне перенести это форматирование в эксель?
И ещё вопрос, (знаю что можно, но не знаю как) как можно, выделяя в гриде какой-то диапазон нажать CTRL+C и перенести его в эксель? Какие свойства надо изменить?
Процедура из предыдущего вопроса копирует всё, а необходимо, чтоб пользователь выбрал определённые данные и перенёс их. Если кто знаком с дополнительными компонентами WPF teleric/DevExpress и др., напишите, пожалуйста, как в них настраивать (может какие-то компоненты кому-то показались лучше, ну или про стандартный грид WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это: [Microsoft Office XML formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats).

Comment: А можно пожалуста понагляднее, как это мне применить в конкретном примере?

Comment: Сгенерируйте xml-файл и открывайте его Экселем.

Answer (score 0):

В DevExpress есть `GridControl`. Там пользователь с помощью фильтров может отфильтровать данные и потом с помощью метода `ExportToXlsx(string fileName)` можно экспортировать в Excel